# If statement check mistake

Tags: python-3.x

I had a code with if statements and the code found the cosine value of the user-defined angle in radial. I typed the code to Taylor Series up to 12!. The code is;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 

teta = np.arange(-8*np.pi, 8*np.pi+0.1,0.1)
P_ = [None]*len(teta)
ang_ = np.zeros(len(teta))

def func(teta):
    for i in range(len(teta)):
        if teta[i]<=0: 
            if abs(teta[i])%np.pi>=np.pi:
                ang_[i] = (abs(teta[i])%(2*np.pi)-2*np.pi)*(-1)
            else:
                ang_[i] = (abs(teta[i])%(2*np.pi))*(-1)
        else:
            if teta[i]%2*np.pi >= np.pi: 
                ang_[i] = teta[i] % (2*np.pi) - 2*np.pi
            else:
                ang_[i] = teta[i] % (2*np.pi)
        P_[i] = 1 - (1/2)*((ang_[i])**2) + (1/math.factorial(4))*((ang_[i])**4) - (1/math.factorial(6))*((ang_[i])**6) + (1/math.factorial(8))*((ang_[i])**8) - (1/math.factorial(10))*((ang_[i])**10) + (1/math.factorial(12))*((ang_[i])**12)
    return P_

plt.plot(teta, func(teta), "b:+")
plt.plot(teta, np.cos(teta), "k--")
plt.grid()
plt.show
```

And the code cannot calculate when the `teta` angle is greater than 6 or -6. when I checked the code by debugging the step, that teta angle is -6.18319, jump over if statement

```
if abs(teta[i])%2*np.pi >= np.pi and teta[i]<-np.pi:
```

and jumps into

```
elif abs(teta[i])%np.pi >= 0 and teta[i]<0:
```

and code transverse the teta value to another angle array named ang_, and it determines by

```
ang_[i] = (abs(teta[i])%(2*np.pi))*(-1)
```

Thus the result of the function is over 2.
I will be glad if you would help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Somehow the code doesn't look right. You should be getting indentation errors or other syntax errors.

Comment: Thnks your comment  mkrieger1. But I don't get any error. by the way I imported all libraries that code required such as numpy, math etc.

Comment: Why are some parts of the code duplicated? (e.g. the definitions of `P_`, `ang_`, and the first 7 lines of `def func(teta)`?

Comment: Is your question why `abs(-6.18319)%2*np.pi >= np.pi` is true?

Comment: Excuse me that is a mistake while I was typing the qs. I edited the post and you can reach the correct code. Apologies again

Comment: The qs is -6.18319 step that condition just you mentioned right now. but it must not pass it. Why does it pass?

Comment: What do you get when you type `abs(-6.18319)%2*np.pi` into an interactive Python session?

Comment: I just closed may computer. But I remembered that i get a value greater than 2. You know cosine cannot be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake and the correct code is;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar  1 13:54:51 2022

@author: burak
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 

user_degree = int(input('cosine value of angle in degree')) / 180 * np.pi
teta = np.arange(-user_degree, user_degree+0.1,0.1)
P_ = [None]*len(teta)
ang_ = np.zeros(len(teta))

def func(teta):
    for i in range(len(teta)):
        if teta[i]<=0: 
            teta = abs(teta)
            if teta[i]%(2*np.pi) >= np.pi:
                ang_[i] = (teta[i]%(2*np.pi)) - 2 * np.pi
            else:
                ang_[i] = (teta[i]%(2*np.pi))
        else:
            if teta[i]%(2*np.pi) >= np.pi:
                ang_[i] = teta[i] % (2*np.pi) - 2 * np.pi
            else:
                ang_[i] = teta[i] % (2*np.pi)
        P_[i] = 1 - (1/2)*((ang_[i])**2) + (1/math.factorial(4))*((ang_[i])**4) - (1/math.factorial(6))*((ang_[i])**6) + (1/math.factorial(8))*((ang_[i])**8) - (1/math.factorial(10))*((ang_[i])**10) + (1/math.factorial(12))*((ang_[i])**12)
    return P_

plt.plot(teta, func(teta), "b:+")
plt.plot(teta, np.cos(teta), "k--")
plt.grid()
plt.show
```

The purpose of this code is to obtain correct cosine values of given angle. I asked the qs that the code cannot step to the correct if condition. for example when the angle is greater than np.pi the resul was above 1. I changed the code as when the angle is lesser than zero and greater than np.pi, code calculates absolute value of angle. Then the step moves to the correct condition. The next calculation is when the absolute value of teta greater then np.pi, the code substructs np.pi. At last the Taylor Series calculation matched with the np.cos() calculation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).